# Adverbs in a complex verb?

Tags: grammar

I want to know if this sentence is grammatically correct.

The actions he took **have truly led** to a lack of confidence in his work.

The words, "have led," are a complex verb. Is it grammatically correct to drop an adverb in-between?

Comment: "Have led" is the present perfect. It is fine on its own. Truly is a modifier that can be easily dropped as it doesn't add anything.

Comment: @jasonkelly:  "Truly" is an adverb.  Adjectives apply to nouns.  Adverbs apply to verbs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example:

> The actions he took have truly led to a lack of confidence in his work.

is grammatically correct. That does not mean that it is good writing. An adverb can be inserted between the parts of a complex verb. There is no rule against doing so. Such an adverb modifies the complex verb. Consider a form like:

> The actions he took truly have led to a lack of confidence in his work.

The meaning is much the same  in this case, and some would consider the construction slightly more awkward.  However, what does "truly" add here. It seems to be just an intensifier, although with more context it might server a more useful function. It might be better simply omitted. But consider a different adverb:

> The actions he took have verifiably led to a lack of confidence in his work.

Here "verifiably"  adds significant information. Presumably the test will go on to show how this is verified, introducing evidence.

In short the problem of whether to use an adverb "inside" a complex verb  is not much different from the question of whether tom use a given adverb at all. An adverb should be used where it enhances the text, and not where it adds little or nothing of value.